# double integer checker function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, filter, arguments

As the title says, this is a double integer checker, meaning it has two functions + the main. Please correct me if I do not paraphrase it correctly. Anyways, here is the model:

```
def is_integer(kraai):

    kraai.replace(" ", "")
    if len(kraai) == 1:
        if kraai.isdigit():
            print(valid)
        else:
            print(invalid)
            exit()

    elif len(kraai) > 1:
        if roek == "-" or roek == "+" or roek.isdigit():
            print(valid)
        else:
            print(invalid)
            exit()

    elif len(kraai) == 0:
        print(invalid)
        exit()


def remove_non_integer(kauw):

    if len(kauw) >= 1:
        for z in kauw:
            if not z.isdigit():
                ekster = kauw.replace(z, "")
                print(invalid)
                print(f'''\nNot all characters after the first are integers...
                \nnogsteeds, vet raaf!:, {ekster}''')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    valid = "valid"
    invalid = "invalid"
    kraai = input("Welcome to the integer tester. Please give an input: ")
    if len(kraai) > 1:
        roek = kraai[0]
        kauw = kraai[1:]
        y = "".join([roek, kauw])
        corvidae = is_integer(kraai), remove_non_integer(kauw)
    elif len(kraai) < 1:
        corvidae = is_integer(kraai)
```

As you can see, one functions to check the integer while the other functions to remove every non-integer. However, three problems:

> It will remove only one unique character
> It will print the same message every time a non-integer is in the integer
> It will print both 'valid' and 'invalid' for some reason when the remove_integer(x) function filters a non-integer.

Any help?

Comment: `kraai.replace(" ", "")` has no effect (strings are immutables) so you need to save the result

Answer (score 0):

So yeah there were multiple errors at the time I posted this question.

```
def is_integer(kraai):

    valid = "valid"
    invalid = "invalid"

    if len(kraai) == 1:
        if kraai.isdigit():
            print(valid)
        elif not kraai.isdigit():
            print(invalid)

    elif len(kraai) > 1:
        if kraai[0] == "-" or kraai[0] == "+" or kraai[0].isdigit():
            if kraai[1:].isdigit():
                print(True)
                print(valid)
            else:
                print(False)
        else:
            print(invalid)

    elif len(kraai) == 0:
        print(invalid)
        exit()


def remove_non_integer(bonte_kraai):

    invalid = "invalid"
    roek = bonte_kraai[0]
    kauw = bonte_kraai[1:]
    y = "".join([roek, kauw])
    for x in kauw:
        if x.isalpha():
            ekster = ''.join([i for i in y if i.isdigit() or i == "-"])
            print(False)
            print(invalid, f'''\nNot all characters after the first are integers...
            \nnogsteeds, vet raaf!: {ekster}''')
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':

    kraai = input("Welcome to the integer tester. Please give an input: ")
    kraai.replace(" ", "")

    if len(kraai) == 1:
        corvidae = is_integer(kraai)
    elif len(kraai) > 1:
        for x in kraai[1:]:
            if kraai[1:].isdigit():
                corvidae = is_integer(kraai)
                break
            elif x.isalpha():
                bonte_kraai = kraai
                corvidae = remove_non_integer(bonte_kraai)
                break
```

> The difference between both codes, now, is first of all that they work individually as observable in the if **name** == '**main**' block.

> Secondly, I used the 'break' statement to break the loop after it has fulfilled its task. Otherwise it will repeat a number of times and that is unwanted (it should only run once).

> Thirdly, as you can see I moved some variables to functions so that pytest doesn't return an 'x is not defined' error. I substituted the variables with indexes [].

Thanks.